# Blazor components get rendered twice

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor page which fetches products from my Db and I then display those products like this

```
@page "/browse"
@using Design_A_Bear.Services
@using Design_A_Bear.Models
@using Design_A_Bear.Client.Pages.components
@inject IItemService ItemService
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

<PageTitle>Browse Products</PageTitle>

<h3 class="fw-bold mt-4 fs-1">Browse Products</h3>
@if(items.Count != 0)
{
    <div class="d-flex mt-5">
        @foreach (var item in items)
        {
            <div class="col-2" @key="item.Id">
                <ItemCard Item="@item" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>

}

@code {
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        items = await ItemService.GetAllItems();
    }

}
```

However, when I run this page the items get rendered then removed and rendered again, so the components get rendered twice. Is there a fix to this?

Comment: it could be ```@rendermode InteractiveAuto``` rendering twice try using a different rendermode : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#render-modes and see if the problem is relative to it

Comment: i have i changed it to @rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly and then InteractiveServer but same thing was happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because blazor components is pre-rendered where its lifecycle methods are called.

If you don't want to do pre-render, you can use the directive below.

```
@rendermode @(new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(prerender: false))
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly went for the honeypot, choosing *Auto* render mode with interactivity set at *Per Page/Component* from the template, without being aware of the consequences of that decision.  `App`, `Routes` and `MainLayout` are being statically rendered on the server.  Every navigation is a round trip to the server with the page being pre-rendered first.

Set Interactivity in `App.razor' to get the full SPA experience.

```cs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Team.Helpers.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet  @rendermode="InteractiveAuto" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveAuto" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```